# Is there a double floating point data type in Godot shaders?

Tags: double, shader, precision, godot

I'm trying to use shaders in Godot and I need a really precise calculation (more than float). Is it possible to have a double in Godot shaders? I searched the documentation but I found nothing...

Edit: I've made a Mandelbrot set explorer and with floats after some zooming the image gets all *pixelated* because the precision limit is reached, I think that with doubles I would be able to zoom further without losing quality. You can check out my code [here](https://github.com/billy4479/GodotMandelbrotSet) btw

Comment: I don't believe so, a lot of GPUs don't support doubles. Could you be more specific about what you need doubles for?

Comment: According to [gpuinfo.org](http://opengl.gpuinfo.org) `GL_ARB_gpu_shader_fp64` and thus [`doubles` in OpenGL shaders](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)) is **supported by 71% of GPUs**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Godot doesn't support FP64 in shaders, since OpenGL 3.3/OpenGL ES 3.0 doesn't mandate support for them on GPUs. Doubles on the GPU are expensive and often crippled on consumer GPUs anyway, making them a bad fit for most real-time applications (especially games that need to run at high framerates).

Comment: Ohh ok, will this be possible when Godot adopts Vulkan as backend?

Comment: I doubt it, since Godot aims to fulfill gaming use cases first and foremost. Even with Vulkan, FP64 performance is still crippled on consumer GPUs. [Supporting double-precision floats for physics on the CPU side](https://github.com/godotengine/godot-proposals/issues/892) is a different thing, and it may be implemented in 4.0.